# How to call a service from another application?

Tags: android, android-service

I have 2 applications, Application A and Application B. Application A is running a service called "MyService". I want to call this service from Application B. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service should have in Manifest `exported="true"` - that is the default value anyway ....

Also add an `<intent-filter>` to the service, with your own custom action string. You may put some permissions to this as well so only the app that has this permission can start. But that's optional.

Then you need to pass an intent that Application A can recognize. So you can use `new Intent("the_action_you_defined_in_A_Service_manifest")` in your call
to `startService()`.

Comment: How do you implement this kind of Service In 2023, -) , I used the IntentService back in time and now IntentService is Deprecated, android doc suggesting use the workManager, not sure how to implement the same with WorkManager